# Smart Contract blockspace allocation in Hybrid Chains

Tags: smart-contract, frame, wasm, pallet-contracts

In [Rob Habermeier's blogpost about Hybrid Chains](https://www.rob.tech/blog/hybrid-chains/), he mentions allocating contract execution to a limited fraction of the chain's blockspace.

Is that some functionality that `pallet-contracts` provides?

Or is it something that needs to be implemented on a different level of abstraction on the `FRAME` stack?

Comment: I looked a little bit into this, but I don't think you can do that currently, the only thing that we can constraint with limit is the DispatchClass (Operational, Mandatory, Normal), these  classes can be given limit and reserved see (https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/limits/struct.BlockWeights.html), but as far as I know we can't do that at the granularity of a single pallet.

Comment: To answer your question, IMO, this kind of abstractions (is not and) should not live in pallet_contracts, since in theory other pallets could benefits from such a granular weight limit system

Answer (score 4):

I looked into this a little bit. It looks like there is nothing built in at the moment.

In frame there is one signed extension [CheckedWeight](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/struct.CheckWeight.html)
that make sure that the weight for a specific [DispatchClass](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/dispatch/enum.DispatchClass.html) (Operational, Mandatory, Normal) does not exceed the configured limit. However this can't be done at the Pallet level.

One solution would be to create a similar signed extension that gives a maximum authorized weights for pallet-contracts extrinsics.

Edit: Looks like this repo offers a pallet that let you do exactly what we want: https://github.com/kalaninja/substrate-differential